# Is an equivelent of reduce in Clojure, whose function takes 3 arguments?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to know if there's a function in Clojure equivalent to this:

```
(defn reduce-1 [f val coll]
  (loop [[head & tail] coll
           out val]
      (if head
        (recur tail (f out head tail))
        out)))
```

Note that this differs from the usual 'reduce in that 'tail is passed to 'f.

I'm using this concept (recursively collect interactions of first and rest of list) so much, that I've started to wonder if there's a standard function for that.

Comment: No, there isn't any such function in clojure. It isn't reduce actually, can you tell exactly for what purpose you need to pass the tail as well to `f`

Comment: @Ankur, I think this is analogous to Schme's pair-fold: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#pair-fold

Answer (score 2):

You could use `iterate`.

```
(defn reduce-with-tail
  [f initial coll]
  (->> (seq coll)
    (iterate next)
    (take-while identity)
    (reduce (fn [initial [head & tail]] (f initial head tail)) initial)))
```